# pip install paramiko comes out with error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have multiple Python versions installed on my ubuntu 20.04 as below:

```
Python3.8.5 is in /usr/bin
Python3.7.9 is in /usr/local/bin
Python3.8.8 is in /usr/local/bin
Python3.9.2 is in /usr/local/bin
```

I am trying to create a virtual environment to run each one of them in different environment:

```
virtualenv -p python3.7 P3.7
virtualenv -p python3.8 P3.8
virtualenv -p python3.9 P3.9
```

when i try to install paramiko package in each virtual environment, only it works on P3.8.
I am getting following error while trying to install in 3.7 and 3.9:

```
$pip3 install paramiko
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in 
    create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in 
    <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 16, in 
    <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, 
    in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in 
    <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in 
    <module>
    from pip._vendor import urllib3
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in 
    <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 39, 
    in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
    File "/home/rutvij/P3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 3, in 
    <module>
    import zlib
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'
```

Comment: It worked on P3.8 as below:
(P3.8) myvm:~$ pip install paramiko
<<snip>>
Installing collected packages: pycparser, cffi, cryptography, six, pynacl, bcrypt, paramiko
Successfully installed bcrypt-3.2.0 cffi-1.14.5 cryptography-3.4.6 paramiko-2.7.2 pycparser-2.20 pynacl-1.4.0 six-1.15.0
(P3.8) myvm:~$ deactivate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22No+module+named+zlib%22

Comment: You need to install zlib development files: `sudo apt install -y zlib1g-dev` and recompile all you Pythons.